# Join three tables into a join table

Tags: sql, database, spring, hibernate, join

I have three entities with Many-To-Many relationship between all of them `User`,`Project` and `Task`. I want to join the three tables into one table `collaborator`that contains only the IDs of the three tables.

But I don't understand how can I join them with `@JoinTable` plus how can I manage the cascade Types.

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks
P.S: if there's any other idea it's welcome.

Comment: you want to join or create a table  named `collaborator`?

Comment: From what you explain, I understand a User can have multiple projects, also a project can have multiple users. The same between projects and tasks. But, in the end, the user is linked with the task via the project, isn't it? I think having other intermediate table would be a lack in your design. If you want it for pure maintainance matters, I suggest you to implement a DB view which will avoid you from writing join queries once and again.

Comment: @ZaidMirza, the `collaborator` is the name of the join table.

Comment: @XtremeBiker, So then I would have a **ManyToMany** relationship between `User`, `Project` and seperately `Project`, `Task` ? and can you explain more on that DB view cause I can't see how will I implement that in code.

Comment: Look at answer below, I agree with that

Comment: I don't know about your model, but, is a user specifically linked to a task? Or the user is linked to projects which are also linked to tasks, which makes the user be linked with tasks in the end? Think about this because creating one more table you might introduce an extra layer of complexity in your project (and make it be denormalized), which maybe isn't required. But, as I say, I don't know about your model, it's only what I infer from your given question.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select from dinamic temp table

```
select * from (
    select user.id, Project.id, Task.id
    inner join Project on user.join_key = Project.join_key
    inner join  Task  on task.join_key = = Project.join_key
) collaborator
```

Comment: it's simple enough for me.Thanks